# Multiple assumptions in integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to add two assumptions, so I can get this probability density function to equal 1, though I can't get a solution.

```
Integrate[(L r x^(r - 2))/(r - 1)! e^(-L x), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> r > 0, Assumptions -> L > 0]
```

[My equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrale&a=%2aC.integrale-_%2aCalculator.dflt-&f2=%28L%20r%20x%5E%28r%20-%202%29%29/%28r%20-%201%29!%20e%5E%28-L%20x%29&f=Integral.integrand_%28L%20r%20x%5E%28r%20-%202%29%29/%28r%20-%201%29!%20e%5E%28-L%20x%29&f3=0&f=Integral.rangestart_0&f4=infinity&f=Integral.rangeend_infinity&a=%2aFVarOpt-_%2a%2aIntegral.variable-.%2aIntegral.rangestart-.%2aIntegral.rangeend--). With the assumptions `r > 0` and `L > 0`

Comment: The exponential function is `E^(...)` or `Exp[...]`.

Comment: Can only give one Assumptions-> option but it can have a List or conjunction (And). So `Assumptions->{r>0,L>0}` would be a correct syntax. I get `Integrate[(L r x^(r - 2))/(r - 1)! e^(-L x), {x, 0, Infinity},                                                                      Assumptions ->{r>0,L>0}] // InputForm                          

Out[2]//InputForm= 
ConditionalExpression[(L*r*Gamma[-1 + r]*(L*Log[e])^(1 - r))/(-1 + r)!, 
 r > 1 && ((Re[Log[e]] == 0 && r < 2) || Re[Log[e]] > 0)]
`

Answer (score 7):

You can make multiple assumptions by passing a list:

```
Integrate[(L r x^(r - 2))/(r - 1)! e^(-L x), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {r > 0, L > 0}]
```

Or, if you prefer, a boolean expression:

```
Integrate[(L r x^(r - 2))/(r - 1)! e^(-L x), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> r > 0 && L > 0]
```

Comment: Hmm ok i tried to get a solution, but as far as i can see, it doesnt not give you 1. Maybe someone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both assumptions :

```
Integrate[(L r x^(r - 2))/(r - 1)! e^(-L x), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {r > 0, L > 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is available analytically with:

Integrate[(L*r *x^(r - 2))/(r - 1)! Exp[-L*x], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> {r > 1, L > 0}]

... with the result

```
(L^(2 - r) r)/(-1 + r)
```

This is unity only for careful choices of L and r so I wonder if your question isn't  about a normalization rather than an absolute check on a probability density function.

Comment: The assumptions are slightly different `(r>1)` and allow Mathematica to find the analytic solution. Also addresses the likely mistyping of 'e' for 'E'...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you are right!