# Mathematica crashes after some iterations

Tags: export, version-8, crash

I wrote a Mathematica script, which calculates an integral value at a list of points and writes it to a file:

```
ϵ :=78.36;
z := 1;
bohr := 0.52917721;
boltzmann = 3.16681535*10^-6;
c := 10 * 6.02214129*10^23*1.0*10^-27*bohr^3;
κ := Sqrt[2.*4*π*c*z];
kBT := boltzmann * 300;

λ = κ/Sqrt[ϵ]*Sqrt[z/(kBT)]

funcin = 
  1/(ϵ*π)*Exp[-(2*r + λ*Sqrt[r^2 + ρ^2 - 2*r* ρ*Cos[θ]])]*
    r^2*Sin[θ]*1/Sqrt[ρ^2 + r^2 - 2*r*ρ*Cos[θ]]

intfuncinang = 
  Assuming[r > 0 && ρ > 0 && ϵ > 0 & &λ > 0, Integrate[funcin, {θ,0,π}, {ϕ,0, 2π}]]

Assuming[ρ > 0 && ϵ > 0 && λ > 0,
  funcins = 
    Integrate[intfuncinang, {r,0,ρ}] + Integrate[intfuncinang,{r, ρ, Infinity}]
  ]//Simplify

dataimport = Import["inputfile.dat", "Table"];
datatoint = dataimport[[1 ;;, 1]]

Print[Length[datatoint]]
int = Array[#&, Length[datatoint]];
Do[ρ = datatoint[[i]];
   int[[i]] = N[funcins];
   points = {datatoint[[i]], int[[i]]};
   points >>> "outputfile.dat"
   , {i, Length[datatoint]}]
```

I run this on the console with  `math -nopromt -run "<<script.m"`. This works always for some values, but crashes after some time. I am using *Mathematica* 8. Does anyone have an idea why I am getting crashes?

Comment: I'm afraid that we would need `inputfile.dat` to try your code :)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `Array[#&,Length[datatoint]]` is just `Range[Length[datatoint]]`. Perhaps `points>>>"outputfile.dat"` could use a `;` to suppress output to the console (I can imagine that a large amount of that may choke the console).

Comment: Another thing: your assignment of `funcins` *within* the `Assuming/Simplify` combo doesn't mean `funcins` contains the simplified result. You have to assign it to the result of the simplification (so outside of the call).

Comment: Thanks already for the comments. I try to suppress the output with ; now, lets see how it works. How can I upload the input file?

Comment: Does not help, still aborting...

Comment: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/d72eed1e here you find the inputfile.dat

Comment: That seems to lead to a .exe file. I'm sorry, but I'm not going to download that. Could you try pastebin.com?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CV8x5ZV0

Comment: please use datatoint = dataimport[[2;;,1]], the first point is not calculatable

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, it leads to the right `.dat` file for me :)

Comment: So is it working for you?

Comment: @Guiste First you are saying `r>0` and then you `Integrate` from `0` to `rho`. That's not possible. And secondly: check [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21217/1356) for how to pass `Assumptions` to `Integrate`.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced kernel crashes like that of *Mathematica* 9.0.1 on OS X in scripts where there is a repeated output to text files during iterations over cycles. Curiously, same scripts run like a charm in Windows, so it is specifically the OS X issue.

Diagnosing this problem is hard, since the kernel just crashes, flushes all variables, and the only message appearing after choosing *Why the Beep?* from the Help menu is "kernel has quit during an evaluation". The crash is somewhat random, i.e. it does not happen at the same points in cycles or for the same data.

I managed to trace the problem (by naive `Print` debugging) to calls of `Export`. Specifically to the variant with `Export["file.txt", data, "Table"]`. Replacing this with `Export["file.txt", data]` fixes the problem. So it may be a bug in `Export`.

You get differently formatted output after the above mention change, with `{}` braces around lists - much like `InputForm` representation . When importing such files, you just do `Import["file.txt", "List"] // ToExpression` instead of `Import["file.txt", "Table"]`.

I'm not sure what platform you working in, but if it is OS X you may be dealing with the same issue. Exporting with the file extension ".dat" produces "Table" format by default, I believe. Try using the extension ".txt" -- easiest of fixes, if it helps.

Comment: Maybe you can get more information by looking at the crash log, or at least sending it to Wolfram support. To find this file, next time a crash occurs open `Utilities > Console` and check the last couple of lines written there. That usually tells you the path and name of the crash log.